# Proving Limit of a function

Tags: analysis

Let $a,b$ be in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $0  < a < b$. Prove that $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty}(a^n + b^n)^{1/n} = b$

How would I go about proving this?

Comment: $\lim_{n \to \infty}$? $\lim_{n \to 0}$? Where does $n$ go to?

Comment: Where are you stuck ?

Comment: Hint: factor out $b^n$

Comment: @YvesDaoust I actually don't even know where to start. Any hints?

Comment: Very clearly, $b^n$ dominates $a^n$. How can you express this ?

Comment: Duplicate of (http://math.stackexchange.com/q/702498) itself a duplicate...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $(a^n + b^n)^{1/n} = b(1+\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^n)^{1/n}$. And notice that $\frac{a}{b} < 1.$